# Narrow down the select options from Text search using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some options in a select tag and a input text box. Once user enters something in text box the related options should be displayed rest needs to be hidden.

```
    <select size="8" style="width:150;">  
    <option value="something1">Apple</option>  
    <option value="something1">Banana</option>  
    <option value="something2">Mango</option> 
    <option value="something2">Orange</option> 
    <option value="something2">Papaya</option> 
    <option value="something3">Grape</option> 
    <option value="something3">Coco</option> 
    <option value="something3">Chocolate</option> 
 </select>
    <input type="text" >
```

When I enter `ap` in text box, only Apple, Papaya should be visible.. Please let me know how I can achieve this by jQuery..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**demo:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/narrow-down-the-select-options-from-text-search-using-jquery

```
        $(function() {
               $('input.search').on('change', function() {
                    $(this).prev('select.term').find('option:not(:containsi(' + this.value + '))').hide();
                }).on('keyup', function() {
                    $(this).prev('select.term').find('option:containsi(' + this.value + ')').show().attr('selected', true);
                }).extend($.expr[':'], {
                'containsi' : function(elem, i, match, array) {
                    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || '').toLowerCase()) >= 0;
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi.. it works.... awesome.. Thanks.. one small enhancement.. when i remove the char, the list is not populating back.. example, `app`gives `apple`, and when I remove p and writes `ap` the list  should give back oprions with `ap`... Thank you very much in advance..

Comment: @Vikram P: i have updated to suit your comment, have nice coding! ps: a +1 will be really appreciated! ;P

Comment: Hello, sorry to resurrect/hijack this, but any idea how to get this to work with a multiple select box?

Comment: @harryg: demo and source updated to support multiple select. have fun.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to search and look at this SO post:

[Jquery: Filter dropdown list as you type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706906/jquery-filter-dropdown-list-as-you-type)

or this example URL

http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/narrowing/