# Using jQuery to narrow down a multiple select box

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a **multiple** select box on a page that contains many options. It can be a pain to scroll through to find the option you need so I want to have an input box that when the user starts typing in it it hides the options in the select box that don't match the text.

Now this is a bit of a duplicate as there is good solution here: [Narrow down the select options from Text search using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008595/narrow-down-the-select-options-from-text-search-using-jquery)

However it doesn't quite do what I want as it seems to not work on multiple select boxes. Can anyone suggest a modification such that it will?

Comment: I would say, show us your code first. You already have a good starting point, so no excuse not trying to do it yourself first....

Comment: jQuery Chosen plugin: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: The solution you linked to now works with multiple select boxes.

Comment: jQuery Chosen actually looks great - I'll give that a shot