# search for values in a large select window: HTML, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select

My onload function returns some 42000 genes. They are all listed in select window. When i click on a gene i get more information.

```
body onload="getLoci();"  
select id="gene" size="60" onchange="getSequenceData(this.value);"
```

Now i am wondering if i can search for a particular gene out of 42000 instead of scrolling and searching manually?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Instead of returning all genes, why not display a filter form first which modified the SQL used to select the genes, and then populate the `<select>` with that result set. Instead of returning all info and filtering it, filter the info and return that.

Comment: standard selects let you type in matches, though that only works for the start of the strings.

Comment: Thank you!
I got it working by
genename:<input type="text" size="7" name = "gene" id="gene" >
                 <input size ="10" type="button" onclick="getSequenceData(gene);" value="search"  />

Answer (score 1):

Check out this thread:   [Jquery: Filter dropdown list as you type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706906/jquery-filter-dropdown-list-as-you-type)

and this example:  http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/narrowing/