# select2 AJAX control disturbs tab ordering

Tags: asp.net, jquery-select2

I am using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) on `dropdownlist` of asp.net. The code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="css/select2.css" />

var v = /* get the select control */
v.select2();
```

The problem is, once `select2()` function is called, tab ordering stops working. Therefore, when on the dropdownlist tab key is pressed, focus do not move to the control having next highest tabindex but move seemingly randomly to some other control.

Commenting the line where the function is called solve this problem but I need the filtering. I have tried some of the other techniques of filtering discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706906/jquery-filter-dropdown-list-as-you-type) but they are too complicated. Select2 is very simple and useful because all you have to do is include the JS and CSS files and call the function.

How can I solve this ordering problem? Alternatively, is there another filtering option as easy to use as select2 that would help me?

Answer (score 3):

After a few hours of struggle, I have solved the problem. It turns out that the select2 AJAX control do destroy the tab order if the tab is pressed as soon as it gets focus, that is, when nothing is typed in it. It does not, however, destroy tab ordering if some text is typed.

The internal structure of select2's auto-generated HTML is like following:

```
<div class="select2-container">
  <a class="select2-choice">
    <span</span>
    <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close" />
    <div> <b></b> </div>
  </a>

  <div class="select2-drop select2-offscreen">
    <div class="select2-search">
      <input class="select2-input select2-focused" tabIndex=<somevalue> />
    </div>

    <ul class="select2-results></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If some text is typed in the HTML select control, then tab ordering is working correctly, if no text is typed then tab order is destroyed. I have used `document.activeElement` in firebug to find focused control in both cases. In case of no text the anchor element has focus, and in case of text typed the HTML input element has focus.

As shown above, while `select2.js` correctly set tabIndex property of HTML input element, it does not of the anchor element.

#### Solution

Just add the following line at the position specified further below in `select2.js`:

```
this.container.find("a.select2-choice").attr("tabIndex", this.opts.element.attr("tabIndex"));
```

Add the line after:

```
this.opts.element.data("select2", this).hide().after(this.container);
this.container.data("select2", this);

this.dropdown = this.container.find(".select2-drop");
this.dropdown.css(evaluate(opts.dropdownCss));
this.dropdown.addClass(evaluate(opts.dropdownCssClass));
this.dropdown.data("select2", this);

this.results = results = this.container.find(resultsSelector);
this.search = search = this.container.find("input.select2-input");
```

and before:

```
search.attr("tabIndex", this.opts.element.attr("tabIndex"));

this.resultsPage = 0;
this.context = null;

// initialize the container
this.initContainer();
this.initContainerWidth();

installFilteredMouseMove(this.results);
this.dropdown.delegate(resultsSelector, "mousemove-filtered",  this.bind(this.highlightUnderEvent));

installDebouncedScroll(80, this.results);
this.dropdown.delegate(resultsSelector, "scroll-debounced", this.bind(this.loadMoreIfNeeded));
```

So it becomes:

```
this.results = results = this.container.find(resultsSelector);
this.search = search = this.container.find("input.select2-input");

this.container.find("a.select2-choice").attr("tabIndex",   this.opts.element.attr("tabIndex")); /* atif */

search.attr("tabIndex", this.opts.element.attr("tabIndex"));

this.resultsPage = 0;
this.context = null;
```

Make this change in `select2.js`. Obviously, you need to use the full js version, not the min version.

All you have to do is add one line, stated above. This would become line no#504 in VS2008 if done correctly.