# Filter large list and show drop down menu once below ~20 "results"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a list that has some ~1000 entries. These will be expanded in the future to as many as ~3000. These entries aren't very easy to remember for the user, but once the user sees the string, they'll be able to identify what they're looking for. Since it's very ugly and browser breaking to show a drop down list containing thousands of entries, I'm trying to think of some way to filter the list as the user types in the query and display the drop down once down to about 20 or so entries.

I can't find any pre-built drop down modules for this functionality. I'm thinking to write some js/jquery that will monitor an input text box and filter the results in the background, and when they hit 20, *change* the text box out for a drop down list with the filtered entries. However, I have no idea how to write this. Is there some better way, or some prebuilt library I can use?

Comment: maybe this is s/t for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154877/use-html5-datalist-autocomplete-with-contains-approach-not-just-starts-wit/32394157#32394157

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery: Filter dropdown list as you type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706906/jquery-filter-dropdown-list-as-you-type)

Comment: have a look at using a filter with the dropdown list. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/706906/jquery-filter-dropdown-list-as-you-type)

Answer (score 0):

I have created this js Fiddle for you, it's in pure HTML, CSS, and javascript.

HTML -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By codeWithAMi - Don't forget to subscribe the channel -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Autocomplete Search Box | CodingNepal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="search-input">
        <a href="" target="_blank" hidden></a>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type to search..">
        <div class="autocom-box">
          <!-- here list are inserted from javascript -->
        </div>
        <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <script src="js/suggestions.js"></script> 
     <script src="js/script.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS -

```
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  background: #644bff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
::selection{
  color: #fff;
  background: #664AFF;
}
.wrapper{
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}
.wrapper .search-input{
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.search-input input{
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 60px 0 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.search-input.active input{
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.search-input .autocom-box{
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.search-input.active .autocom-box{
  padding: 10px 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.autocom-box li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.search-input.active .autocom-box li{
  display: block;
}
.autocom-box li:hover{
  background: #efefef;
}
.search-input .icon{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #644bff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
let suggestions = [
"Channel",
"CODEWITHAMI",
"codeWithAmi",
"YouTube",
"YouTuber",
"YouTube Channel",
"TECH Channel",
"Bollywood",
"Vlogger",
"Vechiles",
"Facebook",
"Freelancer",
"Facebook Page",
"Designer",
"Developer",
"Web Designer",
"Web Developer",
"Login Form in HTML & CSS",
"How to learn HTML & CSS",
"How to learn JavaScript",
"How to became Freelancer",
"How to became Web Designer",
"How to start Gaming Channel",
"How to start YouTube Channel",
"What does HTML stands for?",
"What does CSS stands for?",
```

];

```
// getting all required elements
const searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".search-input");
const inputBox = searchWrapper.querySelector("input");
const suggBox = searchWrapper.querySelector(".autocom-box");
const icon = searchWrapper.querySelector(".icon");
let linkTag = searchWrapper.querySelector("a");
let webLink;
// if user press any key and release
inputBox.onkeyup = (e)=>{
    let userData = e.target.value; //user enetered data
    let emptyArray = [];
    if(userData){
        icon.onclick = ()=>{
            webLink = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${userData}`;
            linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
            linkTag.click();
        }
        emptyArray = suggestions.filter((data)=>{
            //filtering array value and user characters to lowercase and return only those words which are start with user enetered chars
            return data.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(userData.toLocaleLowerCase());
        });
        emptyArray = emptyArray.map((data)=>{
            // passing return data inside li tag
            return data = `<li>${data}</li>`;
        });
        searchWrapper.classList.add("active"); //show autocomplete box
        showSuggestions(emptyArray);
        let allList = suggBox.querySelectorAll("li");
        for (let i = 0; i < allList.length; i++) {
            //adding onclick attribute in all li tag
            allList[i].setAttribute("onclick", "select(this)");
        }
    }else{
        searchWrapper.classList.remove("active"); //hide autocomplete box
    }
}
function select(element){
    let selectData = element.textContent;
    inputBox.value = selectData;
    icon.onclick = ()=>{
        webLink = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${selectData}`;
        linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
        linkTag.click();
    }
    searchWrapper.classList.remove("active");
}

function showSuggestions(list){
    let listData;
    if(!list.length){
        userValue = inputBox.value;
        listData = `<li>${userValue}</li>`;
    }else{
      listData = list.join('');
    }
    suggBox.innerHTML = listData;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Amir_Khan064/04f7qbv5/4/

[image]